# AvroSpecificRecord : Json format

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am getting values in kafkatopic (serialized as avro)

```
"full_address":{"string":"SJS6-L - Alviso, Alviso, California, United States"},
```

Why is "string" included in this ? Isn't it should be a direct json ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your schema and see if `full_address` is a nullable string or not. I've only seen this when it is

Comment: Yes, it is nullable string.

Comment: Okay, so if you don't want `"string"` within the JSON, it needs to not be nullable

Comment: Yes, We want it to be nullable. So, we are using union in avro schema. But while printing we want it to print as normal json

Comment: You are still getting JSON. Not sure what makes it "normal". You simply are getting the JSON represenation of the Avro. There's no way to configure the output, and there are more details in this issue https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/1092

Comment: By normal i meant that it should just contain values and not types. I totally agree that it is how json encoding for union works. But is there a way where it doesn't print the type of value and just directly print the value..  like . ```"full_address":"SJS6-L - Alviso, Alviso, California, United States"```

Comment: I don't know how you're consuming the messages, but you could look at the issue linked, and it requires modifying Jackson properties which are not exposed to the Confluent deserializers

Comment: We are consuming it using kafka avro deserializers.